# TypeError: document.addEventListener is not a function (Node.JS)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dom, discord

JavaScript File:

```
document = path.parse("../html/servers.html");
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
          const avatar = document.getElementById("avatar");
          avatar.src =
            `https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/${userData.data.user.id}/${userData.data.user.avatar}` +
            ".png";
        });
```

HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <title>V0RT3X - Servers</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/output.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div
      class="flex items-center justify-center h-screen bg-discord-gray text-white flex-col"
    >
      <div class="text-2xl">Welcome to the dashboard,</div>
      <div class="text-4xl mt-3 flex items-center font-medium">
        <img
          id="avatar"
          src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/90/Twemoji_1f600.svg/220px-Twemoji_1f600.svg.png"
          class="rounded-full w-12 h-12 mr-3"
        />
        <div id="name"></div>
      </div>
      <a href="/" class="text-sm mt-5">Logout</a>
    </div>
    <script src="../public/servers.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to change the `src=""` of an `img` Tag but for some reason this JavaScript code keeps throwing `TypeError: document.addEventListener is not a function`.

I don't know why this keeps happening, I tried different solutions but none work.

I tried not using `.addEventListener()` and still had issues, I'm not sure if this issue has anything to do with Node.JS or if I'm doing anything wrong but all the Paths look good to me and I'm using correct IDs for `.getElementById`

Comment: The path.parse() method returns an object whose properties represent significant elements of the path. Trailing directory separators are ignored, see path.sep.

The returned object will have the following properties:

dir <string>
root <string>
base <string>
name <string>
ext <string>

Comment: Is there a way where I don't define `document`? Because if I don't I get a `document is not defined`. If not then how exactly should I be linking the `.js` with the `.html` I'm modifying?

Comment: The code you are running in not connect to the html in any way. It runs on the server. If you want to modify the html on the server use jsdom or cheerio. If you want to run this code in the browser, you are doing it wrong

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the js file using Node.js? [path.parse](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#pathparsepath) returns an object and does not load an html file as a DOM.

To run javascript within the DOM you need to load the [javascript file from the html file](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp) and then load the html file in a browser. Then you have access to the global `document`.

Comment: As you can see in my HTML file I have a src attribute set for my JavaScript file in my script tag. Whenever I use "document" in that JS file without defining it to any path it returns a "document is not defined". But what do you mean exactly by load the HTML in a browser?

Comment: I assume `<script src="../public/servers.js"></script>` loads the javascript file then.  But this line `document = path.parse("../html/servers.html");` doesn't make sense. When you open the html file in the browser any loaded javascript will have document defined globally, so there is no need to set it.